# Datatables width not being set correctly

Tags: jquery, datatables

When I try and set the datatable width just the table main section is being resized , in attached image the red circled element should be aligned with main html table. :

[image]

To center the table I use : `$("#myDataTable").css("width","80%");` but as you can see it just resizes the main table section, not the entire datatable.

Comment: When you look at the generated markup, is the select box inside #myDataTable?

Comment: Yes, the select box was not included in the generated markup -    $("#umyDataTable_wrapper").css("width","80%"); did the trick. If you put your comment into an answer I'll accept it, thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

datatables creates a wrapper element which has always the class `dataTables_wrapper` so if you want to resize the table you should resize that element

```
$(".dataTables_wrapper").css("width","80%");
```

if you have more than one table and you want to target a specific wrapper, the id of that wrapper is

```
$("#idofyourtable_wrapper").css("width","80%");
```

Answer (score 0):

Best solution i have come up with thus far:

```
$('#[datatable-id]_wrapper').bind('DOMSubtreeModified', function() {
    $(this).css('width', '150px');
    $(this).css('height', '250px');
});
```

Seems to handle most use cases.

Answer (score 0):

Base the wrapper width on the content table's width:

```
$('#<tableid>_wrapper').bind('DOMSubtreeModified', function () {
  $(this).css('width', $('#<tableid>').css('width'));
});
```